# Deploying artifacts for Java EE projects in IntelliJ, what is an exploded artifact

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, intellij-idea

When I start a JSF Maven project in IntelliJ and edit run configurations, it gives me 2 options to deploy on server:

- project.war
- project.war exploded

How does it know that I will have a war file? That I will have this artifact? Is it from the pom file? What is an exploded artifact?

Comment: Please use `[maven]` tag in future Maven related questions. Maven is not part of Java/JSF/IntelliJ/JavaEE.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- JSF related project ([JavaServer Faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces)) always is a web application. So it will need to be a .war ([Web Application aRchive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format))) file.
- In a general WAR file, all the artifacts of a project are bundled in [zipped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) format. When deployed, many [web containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) by default “explode” (unzip) the war file a regular folder of files ([JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) files, [JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats), or other resources).

In an exploded war format, all the artifacts are in such format so that for each deployment cycle, part of the artifacts of war file can be deployed.

An helpful link is [Advantages/Disadvantages to exploded wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906881/advantages-disadvantages-to-exploded-wars)