# How can I develop on remote server with netbeans

Tags: java, web, netbeans, remote-server

I am developing a java web application with netbeans. The application has to run on a "strong" server and cant run on my computer for testing.

Today I developed and loaded the *.war file with the Tomcat Web Application Manager. This takes a long long time - 10 minutes. I assume that the time is needed to load all files (also libs) to the server each time.

Is there a way to develop with netbeans remote on the server or upload only the edited files?

Thank you!

Comment: I typically develop with IntelliJ and deploy exploded wars http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906881/advantages-disadvantages-to-exploded-wars

Comment: What is your strong server? Does it support remote deployments? JMX?

Comment: Netbeans has a tutorial on running PHP application remotely, hope you can do something similar with J2EE app https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html