# Serve static non-compiled files from J2EE

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm experimenting with J2EE servlets.  My static files are compiled into the WAR.  Is there a way to also allow static files to be served without precompilation? This makes it easy, e.g., to modify Javascript without recompiling? (My goal is experimentation, not production deploy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3906881/2970947

Comment: The modern approach is to use something friendlier like Spring Boot or Micronaut, and Spring in particular makes serving static resources [really easy](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).